# Changing the shape of a view-button

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, drawable

I am trying to do some testing on some views. So I want to create a simple button with a certain shape.

When it's disabled, the button is a rectangle with no color inside like this  :

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ijF1.png)

[image]

I have just used a simple background inside my xml to give this shape to the button (it's inside the drawable, the name is bg_rectangle.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

And here is the xml file with the button inside the layout depository (main_activity.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.laptoplcvn.test1background.MainActivity">

   <Button
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rectangle"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
```

When I tap on it, I want the button to change its shape. I want something like this :

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QPXJ.png)

[image]

I want also to be able to edit the time (00:00 and 05:15) by tapping on the time

And after editing I want the button to be full like something like this :

[pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMUtP.png)

[image]

But I don't have so much idea. I was thinking of creating three others views :
- one view of the button as pic 1
- one view of the button as pic 2
- one view of the button as pic 3

As first the app shows pic 1, then when tapping on it it makes insivible the view pic1, and enables the view pic 2, then after editing it makes invisible view pic 2 and shows pic 3'

Not sure if this works

Any advise ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna try to simplify my answer, hope it helps.

Well, first create a class for Shape Changing like below:

```js
public void setButton(boolean Do, String text, int color) {

  if (Do) {
    YourButton.setText(text);
    // 00:00 and 00:15 to be set on ClickListener

    GradientDrawable shapeDrawable = (GradientDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, listview_background_shape);

    shapeDrawable.setColor(color);

    YourButton.setBackground(shapeDrawable);

    YourButton.getLayoutParams().height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.your_desired_height);
    YourButton.getLayoutParams().width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.your_desired_width);


  } else if (!Do) {
    YourButton.setText(text);
    YourButton.setBackgrountTint(color);
  }

};
```

Now the Only Problem is that In your Picture (Pic2) the letter 'F' is Big then '00:00' is smaller and then 'to' is even Smaller. If you want to Keep it this way, It's better to create Another View just for these texts with The Red background to be Added and when You Click the Button, Button should Disappear.

For now, I assume you want just the button to change without any other views involved.

So, Let's take a look at Click Listener:

```js
int Red = ContextCompabt.getColor(mContext, R.color.your_red_color);
int DefaultColor = ContextCompabt.getColor(mContext, R.color.your_default_grey_color);

MyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if () {
      setButton(true, "F" + text1 + "to" + text2 + "tap to edit", Red);
    } else if () {
      setButton(false, "BUTTON", DefaultColor);
    }



  }
});
```

You should know that setting height and width in `listview_background_shape.xml` is not gonna change the height and width of your button. so you need the button itself to change dimensions.

Let me know if the Answer is not sufficient and you want another View to Appear on Button Click